How can I represent a native Enum with `io-ts`?
If I have an enum like
enum Fruit {
  Apple = 'apple',
  Orange = 'orange',
}

How do I parse these values with an io-ts type?
import * as t from 'io-ts';
const FruitCodec = new t.Type<Fruit, Fruit, unknown>(/* ... */);

Other libraries (for example zod's nativeEnum) have first party support for this feature, but what should I do if I'm using io-ts?

I have come across this problem before, and in the past I've solved it with union or keyof:
const FruitCodec = t.union([
  t.literal(Fruit.Apple),
  t.literal(Fruit.Orange),
]);
// or
const FruitCodec2 = t.keyof({
  [Fruit.Apple]: null,
  [Fruit.Orange]: null,
});

While these approaches work, they feel quite long winded. Generative approaches using Object.values may work but will require type assertions. Hopefully someone else has a more elegant solution.
